# How to understand Laravel Collective like this to HTML

Tags: html, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravelcollective

I get some code laravel collective like this :

```
 {!! Form::select('gender',['-1'=>'Select Gender','Male'=>'Male','Female'=>'Female'],request()->session()->get('gender'),['class'=>'form-control','onChange'=>'ajaxLoad("'.url("laravel-crud-search-sort-ajax").'?gender="+this.value)']) !!}
```

So how can I understand and can someone please encode this code to HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML code

```
<select name="gender" class="form-control" onchange="ajaxLoad("'.url("laravel-crud-search-sort-ajax").'?gender="+this.value)">
    <option value="-1">Select Gender</option>
    <option value="Male" <?php echo (request()->session()->get('gender') == 'Male') ? 'selected' : '' ?> >Male</option>
    <option value="Female" <?php echo (request()->session()->get('gender') == 'Female') ? 'selected' : '' ?> >Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome dude